# How to roll log file on app shutdown in logback?

Tags: java, logback, shutdown, appender

I have a market data Spring Boot application that runs everyday and shuts itself down in the evening. After the app shuts down, I want to process the market data messages which were logged. In order to do that I was looking for a way to be able to rollover the log file at shutdown instead of startup so that my post processing app has a consistent way to read the files.

Currently, I have created a custom triggering policy and a using the following logback config for market data related messages

```
@NoAutoStart
public class CustomTriggerPolicy<E> extends SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP<E> {
    @Override
    public boolean isTriggeringEvent(File activeFile, E event) {
        boolean triggeringEvent = super.isTriggeringEvent(activeFile, event);
        if(!triggeringEvent) {
            elapsedPeriodsFileName = getCurrentPeriodsFileNameWithoutCompressionSuffix();
        }
        return triggeringEvent;
    }
}
```

**logback.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener"/>
    <shutdownHook class="ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DelayingShutdownHook">
        <delay>60000</delay>
    </shutdownHook>
    <appender name="MKT-DATA-FIX-LOG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_HOME}/mkt-data-fix.log</file>
        <append>false</append>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}/archived/foo/mkt-data-fix.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="com.mkt.data.CustomTriggerPolicy">
                <maxFileSize>100GB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
</configuration>
```

**SpringBootApplication.class (Main class)**

```
@PreDestroy
    public void shutdown() {
        manualLogRollover();
    }

    public void manualLogRollover() {
        try {
            Set<Appender<ILoggingEvent>> loggingAppenders = AppenderUtils.getLoggingAppenders();
            AppenderUtils.rolloverAppenders(loggingAppenders);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("Log rollover failed", e);
        }
    }
```

**AppenderUtils.java**

```
public class AppenderUtils {
    public static Set<Appender<ILoggingEvent>> getLoggingAppenders() {
        LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        Set<Appender<ILoggingEvent>> fileLogAppenders = new HashSet<>();
        for(Logger logger : context.getLoggerList()) {
            for(Iterator<Appender<ILoggingEvent>> index = logger.iteratorForAppenders(); index.hasNext();) {
                Appender<ILoggingEvent> appender = index.next();
                if(appender instanceof RollingFileAppender) {
                    if(appender.getName().equals("MKT-DATA-FIX-LOG") ||
                            appender.getName().equals("MKT-DATA-FIX-EVENT-LOG")) {
                        fileLogAppenders.add(appender);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return fileLogAppenders;
    }

    public static void rolloverAppenders(Set<Appender<ILoggingEvent>> appenders) {
        for (Appender<ILoggingEvent> appender : appenders) {
            if (appender instanceof RollingFileAppender) {
                ((RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent>) appender).rollover();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So far I've done the following things;

1. Tried the manual rollover at shutdown without the DelayingShutdownHook which ends up creating a .tmp file and doesn't finish the rollover process cleanly.
2. Add a delaying shutdown hook with a delay of 1 minute but it appears that logback Compressor's asyncCompress method returns a Future that times out after 30 seconds as a result of which I get the following error

```
18:16:58,872 |-ERROR in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@398887205 - Timeout while waiting for compression job to finish java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy.waitForAsynchronousJobToStop(TimeBasedRollingPolicy.java:137)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy.stop(TimeBasedRollingPolicy.java:129)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.stop(RollingFileAppender.java:152)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.detachAndStopAllAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:107)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.detachAndStopAllAppenders(Logger.java:206)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.recursiveReset(Logger.java:331)iam
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.recursiveReset(Logger.java:338)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.recursiveReset(Logger.java:338)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.recursiveReset(Logger.java:338)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.recursiveReset(Logger.java:338)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.reset(LoggerContext.java:223)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.stop(LoggerContext.java:348)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.hook.ShutdownHookBase.stop(ShutdownHookBase.java:39)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DelayingShutdownHook.run(DelayingShutdownHook.java:57)
        at      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am out of options. Does anyone know how to achieve what I am looking for here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I had to define my own triggering and rolling policy that rolled the appenders and compressed the files synchronously.

I don't need to do the rollover as a part of @PreDestroy in my main class.

```
@NoAutoStart
public class CustomTriggerPolicy<E> extends SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP<E> {
    @Override
    public boolean isTriggeringEvent(File activeFile, E event) {
        boolean triggeringEvent = super.isTriggeringEvent(activeFile, event);
        if(!triggeringEvent) {
            elapsedPeriodsFileName = getCurrentPeriodsFileNameWithoutCompressionSuffix();
        }
        return triggeringEvent;
    }
}
```

```
import ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RolloverFailure;
import ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy;
import ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.helper.*;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Custom rolling policy where we trigger rollback at shutdown.
 */
public class MktDataRollingPolicy<E> extends TimeBasedRollingPolicy<E> {

    private static final String LOGBACK_STATUS_FILE_NAME = "logback-status.log";
    private Compressor compressor;
    private RenameUtil renameUtil = new RenameUtil();
    private String basePath;
    private String logbackStatusFilePath;

    FileNamePattern zipEntryFileNamePattern;

    @Override
    public void start() {
        basePath = System.getProperty("logback.statusLog", "/home/master/logs/mkt-data-log");
        logbackStatusFilePath = basePath + File.separator + LOGBACK_STATUS_FILE_NAME;
        super.start();
        // set the LR for our utility object
        renameUtil.setContext(this.context);

        compressor = new Compressor(compressionMode);
        compressor.setContext(context);

        if (compressionMode == CompressionMode.ZIP) {
            String zipEntryFileNamePatternStr = transformFileNamePattern2ZipEntry(fileNamePatternStr);
            zipEntryFileNamePattern = new FileNamePattern(zipEntryFileNamePatternStr, context);
        }
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new ShutdownHookRunnable()));
    }

    @Override
    public void rollover() throws RolloverFailure {
        String elapsedPeriodsFileName = getTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy().getElapsedPeriodsFileName();
        if (elapsedPeriodsFileName != null) {
            if (compressionMode == CompressionMode.NONE) {
                if (getParentsRawFileProperty() != null) {
                    renameUtil.rename(getParentsRawFileProperty(), elapsedPeriodsFileName);
                } // else { nothing to do if CompressionMode == NONE and parentsRawFileProperty == null }
            } else {
                String elapsedPeriodStem = FileFilterUtil.afterLastSlash(elapsedPeriodsFileName);
                if (getParentsRawFileProperty() == null) {
                    compressor.compress(elapsedPeriodsFileName, elapsedPeriodsFileName, elapsedPeriodStem);
                } else {
                    if (isLogFileEmpty()) {
                        addInfo("Skipping compression for empty file: " + getParentsRawFileProperty());
                        return;
                    }
                    renameRawAndCompress(elapsedPeriodsFileName, elapsedPeriodStem);
                }
            }
        } else {
            String msg = String.format("ElapsedPeriodsFileName is null. Skipping rollover for file: %s",
                    getParentsRawFileProperty());
            addWarn(msg);
            File statusFile = new File(logbackStatusFilePath);
            try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(statusFile, true))) {
                bw.append(msg);
                bw.append("\n");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to write to status file: " + logbackStatusFilePath);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    private boolean isLogFileEmpty() {
        File f = new File(getParentsRawFileProperty());
        return f.exists() && f.length() == 0;
    }

    private String transformFileNamePattern2ZipEntry(String fileNamePatternStr) {
        String slashified = FileFilterUtil.slashify(fileNamePatternStr);
        return FileFilterUtil.afterLastSlash(slashified);
    }

    void renameRawAndCompress(String nameOfCompressedFile, String innerEntryName) throws RolloverFailure {
        String parentsRawFile = getParentsRawFileProperty();
        String tmpTarget = nameOfCompressedFile + System.nanoTime() + ".tmp";
        renameUtil.rename(parentsRawFile, tmpTarget);
        compressor.compress(tmpTarget, nameOfCompressedFile, innerEntryName);
    }

    class ShutdownHookRunnable implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                addInfo("Calling rollover inside shutdown hook");
                rollover();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                addError("Failed to rollover", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**logback.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="MKT-DATA-FIX-LOG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_HOME}/mkt-data-fix.log</file>
        <append>false</append>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <rollingPolicy class="com.myapp.logback.MktDataRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}/archived/foo/mkt-data-fix.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="com.mkt.data.CustomTriggerPolicy">
                <maxFileSize>100GB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help someone.

Below is an example of how to use servlet to roll log file in logback on app when servlet container got a shutdown call.

The "ROLLING_FILES" we get from logback xml configuration file.

```
<appender name="ROLLING_FILES" class="com.g5e.store.log.event.LogAppenderConfiguration">
```

After that, we should override "rollover" method.

```
public class LogAppenderConfiguration<E> extends RollingFileAppender<E>
{ 
  @Override
  public void rollover() {
      super.rollover();
  }
}
```

Then we implement ServletContextListener to add a listener for the destroy event.

Get our appender and call "rollover" method on it.

```
@WebListener
public class LogServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener
{
  @Override
  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0)
  {
    LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    LogAppenderConfiguration appender = (LogAppenderConfiguration) lc
        .getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME)
        .getAppender("ROLLING_FILES");

    appender.rollover();
  }

  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0){}
}
```